# How do I push an app in chunks to Appfog?

Tags: appfog

I would like to know if there is a way to specify a folder any specific part that you modified on appfog,when you push or update an app on [appfog](http://appfog.com) it uploads all the content from the current directory you are pushing from but sometimes you modify some part of the app but you dont want to upload the whole app

Appfog has some app size issues when you try to upload,i was wondering if there is a way you can specify a part of your app instead of the whole app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this yet. On every update, your app's file system is destroyed and the app is redeployed on one or more different app instances. This means a partial update would destroy the prior update's files.

AppFog's cloud controller caches files during pushes and updates so that the AF tool does not have to resend unchanged files for each update. If your update fails, try again and it will essentially continue where it left off. Sometimes multiple update retries may be needed to build out this cache. The cache does expire so an update a few days later may need to start over. Files 100mb or larger could still be an issue however.

If your app is content or media rich you could use a **CDN** like amazon S3 to store zips, images, video, and music. This will give your app better performance and speed up your af updates.

Comment: thanks a lot Tim,i though update app_name checked the changes in files  and update them..after moving media to another server it seemed to work but still my application is also big(34Mb) with 26Mb from the framework!