# What is the --path option for in appfogs update command

Tags: appfog

Using appfog, I'm trying to update only a single directory of my site.

```
af update myApp --path some/directory
```

Now, according to this post - [How do I push an app in chunks to Appfog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985239/how-do-i-push-an-app-in-chunks-to-appfog)

This is not a possible task.
So, my question is, what does the --path option do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--path` switch overrides the local root path of your application. It will upload the entire app from that location. This might be useful for scripts that update apps from a different current working directory.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm curious if this is documented somewhere that I missed. I noticed there is also a --debug option that I am also unsure of what it does.